# Aliasing (or typedef'ing) inner class of parameterized class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, inner-classes

Say I have this (stuck with C++03).

```
template <class T, int S>
class FiniteMap
{
public:
    class Iterator {};
    class Entry {};
};

class Foo {};

template <class T, int S>
class FooMap : public FiniteMap<T,S>
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        FooMap<T,S>::Iterator iter;
        FooMap<T,S>::Entry    entry;
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I want to `typedef` `FooMap<T,S>::Iterator` and `FooMap<T,S>::Entry` but if I try this:

```
typedef FooMap<T,S>::Iterator FooIterator;
```

I get "error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope".  If I try putting template parameters on it:

```
typedef
    template <class T, int S>
    FooMap<T,S>::Iterator FooIterator;
```

I get "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘template’".
I have resorted to using a #define:

```
#define FooIterator typename FooMap<T,S>::Iterator
```

This seemed to work (although it doesn't work on [Online C++ Compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ2Z56aqS)).

Seems kind of hackish though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `typedef FooMap<Foo,5>::Iterator FooIterator;` ?

Comment: I need to keep T and S abstract.

Comment: C++03... yep... this is the whole reason they introduced `using` in C++11...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 has `using for this :)

When I tried on C++03, I got the error "need `typename` before `FiniteMap` as it is a dependent scope...

Thus:

```
template <class T, int S>
class FiniteMap {
public:
    class Iterator {};
    class Entry {};
};

class Foo {};

template <class T, int S>
class FooMap : public FiniteMap<T, S> {
public:
    typedef typename FiniteMap<T, S>::Iterator FooIterator;
    typedef typename FiniteMap<T, S>::Entry FooEntry;

    void bar()
    {
        FooIterator iter;
        FooEntry    entry;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FooMap<int, 3> test;

    return 0;
}
```

[On GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/I1cnCL)

Comment: Yes, I also discovered that seems to work.  Unfortunately it doesn't really make external code that much cleaner.   I would still have to do `FooMap< _classname_ , _size_ >::FooIterator myiter;`.  But this at least cleans up internal-class code.

I can always typedef in my user .h files.

Thanks!

Comment: Ugh I guess italics and code formatting don't work together.

Comment: @livefree75 You wasn't clear on what you wanted... and c++03 is 16 years old...

Comment: Tell that to my employer.

Comment: @livefree75 ok, give me his email address.

Comment: I'm sure they would appreciate that.
The truth is, this is for a critical system running on multiple platforms, with dozens of developers and many domestic and foreign customers, and it has to go through multiple levels of testing and approval.  Upgrading has been discussed, but not by me... Way above my pay grade.  It's not as easy as simply downloading the lastest version.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
typedef FooMap<T,S>::Iterator FooIterator;
```

compiler complains about T (and probably S) not being declared - and I have to agree.
If you want to keep T abstract, then you are stuck with using the parameterised template.

But I think you actually want to typedef a "short" for the specific case of T=Foo and S=5.
That can be done this way

```
/* ... start of your file */
class Foo {};
typedef FooMap<Foo,5>::Iterator FooIterator;
int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to update my initial example.  I do need to keep T and S abstract.

Comment: What if I were to do the typedef inside my FooMap class?

Comment: You relevantly changed the question after this answer. That is called a moving target question and usually not appreciated.

Comment: Sorry.  What's the proper etiquette?  I realized I wasn't clear on my question after I received your answer.

Comment: In order to get an answer to your actual question, make another one. Contrast it to the misunderstood one by stressing the new changed details, to make sure that it is not misunderstood again and also that it does not attract "duplicate" votes. If that still seems too similar, add something like "In contrast to that (link) other of my questions..." to explicitly, but subtly, tell people that it is not a duplicate. I think I would do that not before the second paragraph of explanation, in the hope of creating a more confident impression.